# Merging two columns but only unique combinations

Tags: sql, unique

I have two columns, each with identification numbers that have been brought in from different datasheets.

I want to combine this into one column with both identification numbers if they are different, but only one of the identification numbers if they are the same.

I'm using `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(column 1, column 2) AS column 3` to combine the columns, but can not filter out `UNIQUE` combinations.

When I try `WHERE column 1 <> column 2`, I get an error message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which sql database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE WHEN` to test for conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN column1 = column2 THEN column1
                     ELSE CONCAT(column1, column2)
                     END AS column3
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this using IIF or CASE and CONCAT

```
select
distinct
iif(col1<>col2,concat(col1,col2),col1) [myid]
from mytable
```

or

```
select
distinct
case when col1<>col2 then
     concat(col1,col2)
else col1 end [myid]
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN column1 = column2 THEN column1
                     ELSE column1 + '|' + column2
                     END AS combinedColumn
FROM table1
```

Consider the following chart:

```
column1  column2  column1+column2   column1+'|'+column2
12       34          1234                 12|34
123      4           1234                 123|4
1234     1234        1234                 1234
```

Also, column1+column2 loses some information - what the original parts were.